# How to divide string's length by 2 and then print sliced version based on result in one line

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
my_daily_thought = "I am the first half I am the second half"
print(len(my_daily_thought)//2)
```

How can i print "I am the second half" after finding my_daily_thought variable's divided length in one line?

Output should be "I am the second half" instead of 20.

@dreadnaught thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat strings in python as a list of characters and thus slice it as such:

```
my_daily_thought = "I am the first half I am the second half"
print(my_daily_thought[:len(my_daily_thought)//2])

print(my_daily_thought[len(my_daily_thought)//2:])
```

note that you can leave the 0 out in: `my_daily_thought[0:10]` to express that you slice from the start. Just like you can slice until the end as in the second slice

In your code you call the print() function on the statement: `len(my_daily_thought)//2` but this statement evaluates to a number (as `len()` evaluates to the length of the array and dividing it by 2 also returns a number) and so that is why you print the number 20